# Question about proportion of Nim positions

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, combinatorial-game-theory

Let a Nim game be represented by a sequence of positive integers. We call a Nim of *size* $n$ when the sum of its elements is $n$.

Let $a(n)$ be the number of Nim games of size $2n$ with Nim sum 0. Similarly, let $b(n)$ be the number of Nim games of size $2n$ with Nim sum 2.

I'm trying to prove (or possibly disprove) $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a(n)}{b(n)}=1.$$

I've calculated the first values with help of a computer; by $n=250$, this fraction is about $1-10^{-50}$, so there's clearly some convergence going on. I haven't been able to prove it, however. I've been trying to establish some sort of "partial bijection" between the sets of Nim games of Nim sum 0 and 2, but that hasn't worked. I've tried using recursion, I've gotten nothing. Any help?

Comment: Intuitively, I am not surprised.  Given an position with sum $0$ you can make one with sum $2$ by adding a pile of $2$.  Similarly, given one of sum $2$ you can make a pile of sum $0$ by adding a pile of $2$.  Yes, each of these increases $n$ by $2$, but for large $n$ this doesn't matter.  There are theorems of equilibrium distributions in Markov chains that may apply, but I haven't studied those.  I suspect you can prove that for $n$ large enough, the positions of value $k$ have similar cardinality when  $k \ll n$

Comment: @RossMillikan: I think "for large $n$ this doesn't matter" is wrong in this case, though, since the growth of $a(n)$ and $b(n)$ is exponential.  For instance, $a(n+2)\geq 2a(n)$ since given a game of size $2n$ you can turn it into a game of size $2n+4$ by adding either $(2,2)$ or $(1,1,1,1)$ to the end.  So, your argument shows $a(n)\leq b(n+1)\leq a(n+2)$ but this doesn't give a strong bound on the ratio $a(n)/b(n)$.

Comment: @bof Yes, I've fixed that.

Comment: What happens if you only look at $a(2^k)/b(2^k)$ for integer $k$?

Comment: Does order matter when counting Nim positions? That is, is $(2,1,1)$ considered distinct from $(1,2,1)$?

Comment: @MichaelLugo I'm not sure if it's any better to just look at them. It doesn't seem much more well behaved. And to prove the general result from this one, the function $\frac{a(2n)}{b(2n)}$ would need to have a degree of regularity I haven't been able to prove.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yes, they're sequences.